# java guessing game runs but doesnt run correctly

Tags: java

Cant figure out what I am doing wrong in my java guessing game program.  The computer picks a number between 1 and 100 and the user is asked to guess it.  User is prompted with too low or too high and asked to guess again until they get it right.  My problem is that when you guess the number right, it will always say too low, but then if you type the same number again it will say correct.

```
package guessinggame;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class GuessingGame {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        int guesses;    //number of users guesses

        int housePick;  //number the user must guess

        int guess;      //users guess

        guesses = 0;

        housePick = (int)((Math.random() * 100) +1 );  
        //sets housePick to random number from 1 to 100

        System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number between 1 and 100") ;
        //print "Im thinking of a nubmer between 1 and 100"

        System.out.println("Can you guess what it is?");
        //print "can you guess what it is"

        System.out.println
                ("Enter a number from 1 to 100 (including 1 and 100)");
        //prompt user to enter number

        System.out.println("test " +housePick );
        //Test: tells user the correct answer
        do
        {
            guess = input.nextInt();

            if (guess > housePick)  //and if guess > housePick...
            {
                if ((guess - 10) <= housePick )  
                    //and if guess is 10 numbers away from housePick...

                {
                    System.out.println("Close, but too high. Try again.");
                    //print "close but too high, try again"

                    guesses = guesses+ 1 ;



                }

                else              //if guess is not close and guess>housePick...
                {
                    System.out.println ("Too high, try again.");  
                    //then print "Too high, Try again"

                    guesses = guesses+ 1;


                }                         
            }
            else  //If guess<housePick
            {
            if ((guess + 10) >= housePick)  //AND if guess is close to housePick
            {
                System.out.println ("close, but too low.") ; 
                //then print "close, but too low"

                guesses = guesses + 1;

            }
            else//If guess isnt close to housePick and is less than housePick...
            {
                guesses = guesses+ 1;

                System.out.println ("Too low.");//then print "too low"
            }

            }

        }while (guess != housePick);  //while guess doesnt = housePick...

          guess = input.nextInt();
        //save entered number as guess

    guesses = guesses + 1;

        System.out.println ("You win!  It took you "  +  guesses + " guesses.");
        //If guess = housePick print "Yout win! It took you (# of guesses)"




    }
}
```

Comment: What have you done to debug it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else  //If guess<housePick
```

You're wrong with above condition, it is equivalent to `guess <= housePick`. it must be

```
else if( guess < housePick)
```

Also, Following block of code is executed when `housePick == guess` so there's not point of doing `guess = input.nextInt()`, You can simply say *You Win*.

```
}while (guess != housePick);  //while guess doesnt = housePick...

  // At this point, guess == housePick, why ask for input again????

        //  guess = input.nextInt(); 
        //save entered number as guess

    //guesses = guesses + 1;
```

Comment: wow. Cant believe i couldn't figure that one out.

Comment: @user2809114 Such things happen. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

You also have an extra input.nextInt() after the while:

```
}while (guess != housePick);  //while guess doesnt = housePick...

guess = input.nextInt();
//save entered number as guess
```

Delete it

Answer (score 0):

Lets see

Housepick = 87

guess = 87

```
if ((guess + 10) >= housePick)  //AND if guess is close to housePick
{
       System.out.println ("close, but too low.") ; 
       //then print "close, but too low"

       guesses = guesses + 1;

}
```

hmm 87 + 10 IS greater than 87

And then it breaks the do/while loop and you are prompted again